# Copying information from a master sheet to it's feeder sheets.

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work book that I am using to track volunteer hours.  I often get new volunteers.  Is there a code I can use to add a line item in each month from when I add a name to the master.

EX> of master sheet

```
A1 = Jimbo A2 = Jones
B1 = Mike  B2 = Smith
C1 = Tommy C3 = Tickles
```

If I want to make on the master

```
B1 = Kyle  B2 = Tanner
```

How do I automatically make the following sheets add Kyle Tanner in Row B
Jan, Feb, March, April, May, June, July, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec

Thanks all, I appreciate it, I think this is going to be easy for someone but it's stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Basic Editor (Alt + F11) and In Left Top Pane you can find your Master Sheet under

**VBA Project -> Microsoft Excel Objects -> Master Sheet**

Open Master Sheet and Paste This Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim VarRow, VarCol, VarVal, VarSheets, Sheet
VarRow = Split(Target.Address, "$")(2)
VarCol = Split(Target.Address, "$")(1)
VarVal = Target.Value
VarSheets = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec") 'Your Feeder Sheet names
For Each Sheet In VarSheets
Worksheets(Sheet).Range(VarCol & VarRow).Value = VarVal
Next
End Sub
```

Let me Know you got any issues